# Pandas reading CSV with ^G as separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

The CSV file has a delimiter of **^G**. I am using pandas, the current separator is a comma. I have a new requirement to read the **^G**-separated CSV. Are there any supported libraries associated? Also, all the columns are enclosed in quotes.

Sample CSV data

```
"2198"^G"data"^G"x"
"2199"^G"data2"^G"y"
"2198"^G"data3"^G"z"
```

Based on the suggestion I tried below command

```
 df = pd.read_csv(f, engine="python", sep=r"\^G", header=None, names=columns, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

I get the output below

```
{"col1":"\"2198\"","col2":"\"data\"","col3":"\"x\"}
```

How do I remove the quote marks and slashes for the data in the final output?

Comment: Warning flag: Is the separator actually the two-character sequence "caret, gee" or is it a single BEL character (code point 7, sometimes written, for historical reasons, as control-G or ^G)?

Comment: The seperator  is  ^G and all the columns are enclosed in double quotes

Comment: You have not answered the question. Is this a literal sequence of two characters where the first is `^` or are you using this notation to refer to the single control character ctrl-G? (The notation `r"\^G"` looks to me like two characters, but I'm not a Pandas person.)

Comment: Removing quotes should be standard in proper CSV libraries; experiment with their quoting options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `engine='python'` and escape `^` because special regex character:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=r"\^G", engine='python')
```

EDIT: You can use converter with `strip` for remove `"`:

```
columns = list('abc')

df = pd.read_csv(file,
                 engine="python", 
                 sep=r"\^G",
                 header=None, 
                 names=columns, 
                 converters=dict.fromkeys(columns, lambda x: x.strip('"')))
    
print (df)

      a      b  c
0  2198   data  x
1  2199  data2  y
2  2198  data3  z
```

Comment: @jazrel. Thanks your code helped me complete some parts of the work and I am stuck with quoting issue in the final output. Can you please help?